# Can't find the namespace of assembly after change assembly location

Tags: c#

:( the testing project was on different client profile ...

Problem solved when change it.

---

I create some project that contain GUI - after compile this project i get dll and i can call the 'Show' method to see the dialog of the GUI.

I change the dll output path to the global bin of the project - and now my testing project that doing just the show dialog does not fine the namespace of the dll.

I deleted the reference of the dll and set it again with the location of the global bin directory - and i get again the error message

The type or namespace name 'XXXXXXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

I see this message only when i try to run the testing project in the first time after i re-set the dll location ==> that mean that in the compile time the testing project sees the dll and his namespace with no problem.

How to solve this ??

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear, an assembly's location should not affect the namespaces. So it's a dependency on some other dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:( 
the testing project was on different client profile ...

Problem solved when change it.